# PySpark regex to filter invalid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from dataframe column

Tags: regex, dataframe, pyspark, ipv6, ipv4

I have the following line in code:

```
.filter((~f.col("DestinationIP").rlike("^([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})\\.([0-9]{1,3})$")) | 
                            ~f.col("DestinationIP").rlike("^([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,7}:|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,6}:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,5}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,2}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,3}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,4}|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,2}(:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,5}|[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,6})|:((:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}){1,7}|:)|fe80:(:[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}){0,4}%[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,}|::(ffff(:0{1,4}){0,1}:){0,1}((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])|([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){1,4}:((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])\.){3,3}(25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1{0,1}[0-9]){0,1}[0-9])"))
```

But I am getting this error message:

> raise ValueError('%r does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address' %
> ValueError: '016301004081' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address

How to resolve this? I want only valid IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to remain in my column and filter out all other rows.

Comment: could you show the full code, seems like the exception was raised by Python's ipaddress lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably remove the `~` symbols which in Spark is equivalent to `NOT`.

Your current filter keeps rows which **do not match** either of conditions. If you have IPv4, it may not match IPv6 condition, so the value remains. The same goes for `016301004081` - it does not match any condition, so it remains.

Instead of:

```
Keep:
    (NOT IPv4)
    OR
    (NOT IPv6)
```

after the change you would have

```
Keep:
    IPv4
    OR
    IPv6
```